# Formula logic for extracting specific cell data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For extracting First £ figure and not the second one from sample data

(24M UNLTD+INS 30GB £347+£30 S6)

Following array formula has been used in Stackoverflow questions.

```
   {=MID(A1,FIND("£",A1),MIN(IF(ISERROR(MID(MID(A1,FIND("£",A1)+1,999),ROW($1:$999),1)+0),ROW($1:$999),999)))}
```

I attempted an analysis of the formula as represented in the image below. I am not able to grasp the logic of part

```
MIN(IF(ISERROR(MID(MID(A1,FIND("£",A1)+1,999),ROW($1:$999),1)+0),ROW($1:$999),999))
```

As to how it leads to a figure of 4. Request that this part of formula be elaborated to clarify the role of various constituents of this formula.

[image: ste by step working on formula]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following as a standard (non-array) formula,

```
=--REPLACE(REPLACE(A2, 1, FIND("£", A2), ""), FIND("+", REPLACE(A2, 1, FIND("£", A2), "")), LEN(A2), "")
```

First the inside `REPLACE(A2, 1, FIND("£", A2), "")` erases everything up to the first **£** symbol, then the same logic is applied to erase everything in that modified text from the first **+** to the end. The `--` converts text-that-looks-like-a-number to an actual number.

The array formula you provided uses a more convoluted logic.

1. `FIND("£", A2) + 1` finds the starting point of the first number after the first **£** symbol. e.g. The first £ is the 20<sup>th</sup> character so it returns 21.
2. `MID(A2, FIND("£",A2)+1, 999)` extracts the text following that first £ symbol. The text might look like it starts with a number but it is text masquerading as a number. e.g. 347+£30 S6
3. In an array formula, `ROW($1:$999)` processes as a sequence of numbers from 1 to 999, incrementing by 1 for each cycle of calculation.
4. `MID(MID(A1, FIND("£", A1) + 1, 999), ROW($1:$999), 1) + 0)` returns an array of text values, each one 1 character long and 1 position deeper into the text than the previous one. e.g. `3`, `4`, `7`, `+`, `£`, etc.
5. `+0` is used to try and convert each of these pieces of text to a number. The IFERROR function returns TRUE if a piece of text cannot be converted to a true number. The first one that cannot be turned into a true number is the 4<sup>th</sup> e.g. `+`
6. The `IF` catches the TRUE on the fourth position and returns 4 from the second `ROW($1:$999)`. It has returned `999` for positions 1, 2 and 3. e.g. 999, 999, 999, 4, 5, etc.
7. The `MIN` catches the smallest of these numbers returned as an array. This is where the **4** comes from. e.g. `999, 999, 999, 4, 5, 999, ...`

You can see this yourself by changing all of the 999's to 9 then using the [Evaluate Formula](https://goo.gl/Vl25be) command. The reason changing to 9 is important is so that the returned arrays of number look like *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9* which does not obfuscate the results quite a badly as *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ... 998, 999*.

[image: evaluate_formula]
      <sub>This shows the formula evaluated several steps into the process. Note the **4** being returned to the [MIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-735E28B8-829A-413A-BA38-668FCF0520D7).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response and suggestion. I have deep respect for your knowledge and experience. I would appreciate If you could clarify on my difficulty in understanding MIN part of array formula as it also occurs frequently in various situations.

Comment: That part take a little longer to write and explain. I hope what I provided above suffices.

Comment: I profusely thank you for clarifying me various steps in formula and its related logic . Now things are crystal like clear to me.

Comment: Small error in logic interpretation that did not affect the results corrected above.